# AdjustThreadsInPool , Thread Abort Exception

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having this exception in my C# application....

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.AdjustThreadsInPool(UInt32 QueueLength)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItemHelper(WaitCallback
callBack, Object state, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean compressStack)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback callBack, Object state)
   at burhanClient.RowDeleterThreadManager.Push(String
message)
   at burhanClient.DeleteRow(Object OrdId)
```

In `DeleteRow ()` ... I am deleting a row from grid after some sleep time.... here is the code below :

```
public void DeleteRow(object OrdId)
{
    try
    {
        string OrderID = OrdId.ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(GlobalSettings.GetSettings().OrderDisappearTime);
        string query = ColumnOrderID.Name + " ='" + OrdId + "'";
        LiveOrdersDS.OrdersRow[] rows = CustomSelect(query);
        if (rows.Length > 0)
        {
            string status = converter.convertOrdStatus(rows[0].ColumnStatus.ToString());
            if (OrdStatus.FILLED == status || OrdStatus.CLOSED == status || OrdStatus.CANCLED == status)
            {
                // Start Temp Code
                logger.Info("Order: (" + OrderID + ") Deleting Row From Blotter");
                // End Temp Code
                RowDelThdManager.Push(OrderID);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SendMail(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you until you explain why you are aborting threads.  And why you'd want to send yourself an email about it :)

Comment: I am aborting threads when that particular WINDOW/FORM is closed,, al threads related to it should be closed... and sending email cos there is no app crash... during this exception so i put SendMail code here so that i get email about this exception..... kindly help :/

Comment: Meh, leave it be, good to be reminded that you are doing something very, very wrong.

Comment: If anyone can help me HOW and WHY this exception "AdjustThreadsinPool" is generated... i'll be very much thankfull....

Comment: @HansPassant :: what's wrong ?? explain  please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort)

Comment: No No check my answer

Comment: Well, that was very, very wrong.  At least explain the wrong-ness in the answer, it is not very clear what a "dead thread" could look like.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.. The ThreadPool was generating it, I was keep pushing the same DEAD thread to ThreadPool thats why this error was occuring.
Thanks guys.